# how to handle neo4j node load light exception

Tags: neo4j

We are running our application with neo4j 
where the graph db is embedded but running in HA mode with 3 servers and 3 zookeper services.
When ever there is a switch that is happeninng from master to slave 
we are seeing node load light and BlockReadTimeoutExceptions in the slave node and after that 
we are seeing internal shutdown message in the messages.log.

From then on no other requests are being processed . 
Could you please help us .

Thanks,
Sampath.

Comment: Could you post the text of the errors?